# javascript publish subscribe with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Scenario :- a json with checked & unchecked item count needs to be sent to a common function which in turn does some basic validation or shows error. There are different function each handle by different css/js team which call this function & depending on the common function result (true/false) each team/module that provided the json with check/uncheck status does the relevant action. Thus both common function (say getcount) & every independent team calling this function rely on the result of common function manipulate the dom/css independently & the common function too manipulate dom independently.

Instead of conventional way of calling function (say getCount({"chk" : 2 , "unchk" : 4})) i am looking for pusblish/subcribe method which is more cleaner as in Jquery & easy to convey to all as only topic name & contract/json needs to describe (also less if/else clause). Since common function is subscriber & when every independent function publishes the resultant chk/unchek json the common function can easily do the manipulation using the publish/subscribe approach but the independent method has to do counter action as well which is only possible if subscribe function can send the result. I know javascript is asynchronous also i understand that common method can publish (say "resultOfGetCount") which every independent function/module can listen to & do the action but is there any way in either in plain javascript or jquery where in on which subscriber can send the publisher the result in a way similar to $.ajax where in the callback function is called once server call is complete.

Looking for the best approach for such scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple publish subscribe model in jQuery from this [blog post](http://benmccormick.org/blog/2013/02/13/simple-publish-subscribe-with-jquery/)

```
var exampleHandle = function(){
    //do stuff when topic is published
    ...
}

function subscribe(topic,handle){
    $("#subscription").bind(topic,handle);
}

function publish(topic,params){
    $("#subscription").trigger(topic,params)
}

function unsubscribe(topic,handle){
    $("#subscription").unbind(topic,handle);
}
```

where you can use a simple string as a topic to subscribe or unsubscribe to the topic, and attach the handle as a callback function.  The handle can also be used to unsubscribe from the topic later if necessary.

> The method is based on jQuery’s trigger and bind functions. These
> allow you to listen for a custom event on an element, and manually
> trigger an event on an element. This provides the basic backbone for
> the simple subscription model.
>
> If an application element wants to
> subscribe to a topic, they bind a handler to the “subscription
> element”. This can be a designated element on the page, or just the
> window element. You can also of course use different elements for
> different subscriptions. Then, when something publishes to that topic,
> the handler function will execute.
>
> For publishing, a function can pass
> a topic and parameters to the publish function. This calls jQuery’s
> trigger to set off the event topic, passing along the parameters.
> These params are passed to the handle function.
>
> If an element wants to
> cancel its subscription, they can pass the topic and handle function
> to the unsubscribe method. Note that the handle has to be the same
> function object that was used to originally subscribe, not a copy or
> similar function. You also can use jQuery’s unbind to cancel all
> subscriptions to a topic by only specifying the topic without the
> handle function.

Comment: let say  we bind using a callback/handle function doAfterGetCnt $("#subscription").bind("getcount",grp1.doAfterGetCnt()) here grp1 is the namespce & .doAfterGetCnt() is callbk func , in this case we are binding only to one method but subrcribr should callback different function say grp2.getCntAfter() as you see both namespace & callback method name is change as they belong to different team & follow diffrent convention. I want more generic way to handle situtation & in this case the subscriber should be able to call different methods & publisher should pass the callbk func name is fine too!!

Comment: huh?  I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  If you have more concerns why don't you edit your question and include some code examples and I can try to help.

Comment: I think i have a idea i guess $.publish & $.subscribe method will do as well we can pass method name & look for dynamce function callback can do the rest!!